# readOGR(), "cannot open file" error

Tags: r, shapefile, rgdal, ogr

Let me begin by saying that I have exhaustively looked at the other threads that have dealt with readOGR errors, and have made several attempts to implement them for my own benefit.

The issue I have is similar to questions previously addressed: that is to say that I cannot import a shapefile via readOGR.

My working directory is :

`("~/Desktop/R_Thesis_Project")`

Please not that I realize that this not the full working directory. I have entered that as well for the 'dns' and that produces the same result.

The shapefile (which includes the .shp, .dbf, .xml, .shx, and .prj is found in:

`("~/Desktop/R_Thesis_Project/Shapefile")`

Note that there is no ".shp" extension to this folder.

I have confirmed that this folder is indeed in my working directory by using:

`list.files("~/Desktop/R_Thesis_Project")`
and

`file.exists("~/Desktop/R_Thesis_Project/Shapefile")`

Yet when I do the following two variations, I get the following errors:

`Shapefile=readOGR("~/Desktop/R_Thesis_Project","Shapefile")`
`Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open file`

and if I try to move the Shapefile folder to a different folder in my directory (i.e. the "Data folder"), I get the following error:

`Shapefile=readOGR(".","/Data/Shapefile")
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open layer`

I'm not sure if it is worth mentioning that this shapefile was downloaded from a Box folder. Furthermore it has never been opened in other applications such as ArcGIS. I do not have ArcGIS on my desktop.

I've been growing incredibly frustrated that I cannot read this shapefile into R. Any and all recommendations/help is appreciated!

-Thanks in advance,

M

Comment: Difficult to diagnose unless you make the file available. You could try qgis to check file isn't corrupt

Comment: Try: `shp <- readOGR(dsn=path.expand("~/Desktop/R_Thesis_Project"), layer="Shapefile")`  or possibly: `dsn <- readOGR(dsn=path.expand("~/Desktop/R_Thesis_Project")) ; ogrListLayers(dsn)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check inside the Shapefile folder if the `.shp`, `.dbf`, `.xml`, `.shx`, and `.prj` files are actually named as Shapefile. I did that and it helped . I hope it helps you too

Comment: Sorry I never got around to accepting this, that did the trick ;)